# Partial String Match - Dynamic Strings

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, optimization

For certain dynamic strings like:

- covid-19 testing status upto may 05,2021
- covid-19 testing status upto may 04,2021
- covid-19 testing status upto may 01,2021
- ....
- covid-19 testing status upto {{date}}

and others like:

- Jack and Jones are friends
- Jack and JC are friends
- Jack and Irani are friends
- .....
- Jack and {{friend-name}} are friends

I want to match the incoming string like:

```
covid-19 testing status upto may 01,2021
```

with

```
covid-19 testing status upto {{date}}
```

and if there is a match, I want to extract the value of `date`.

Similarly, for an incoming string like

```
Jack and JC are friends
```

I want to match with

```
Jack and {{friend-name}} are friends
```

and extract `JC` or the friend-name. How could I do this?

I am trying to create a setup where dynamic strings like these, can be merged into one. There could be thousands of incoming strings that I want to match against the existing patterns.

```
INCOMING_STRINGS -------EXISTING-PATTERNS-----> 
   [
    covid-19 testing status upto {{date}}, 
    Jack and {{friend-name}} are friends, 
    ....
   ] ---> FIND THE PATTERN AND EXTRACT THE DYNAMIC VALUE
```

**EDIT**

It is not guaranteed that the pattern will always exist in the incoming strings.

Comment: You could define a regular expersion for each pattern and check if they match.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Could you help answer for the 2 sample strings I have posted in the question? It will help.

Comment: It depends, if `Jack and {name}...` or `covid-19 testing... {date}` always exist, then using for loop is fair enough, otherwise you wouldn't be able to extract date or name exactly, you can define a simple similarity function (ex. name usually starts with a capital letter), (dates commonly consist of numbers and a specific delimiter).

Comment: if the pattern is complex or no pattern exists, then you need to train an AI model (Natural Language Model) for your objective, if you just want to match strings with each other then `cosine-similarity` would be fine.

Comment: @4.Pi.n There could be millions of incoming strings and from those, I need to match for the existing patterns.

Comment: Please mention if the pattern is always exist or not (guaranteed) in your question (be specific) to be able to help, so number of strings (millions or billions) have nothing to do with which problem you actually facing.

Comment: @4.Pi.n Updated my question. The pattern may or may not exist.

Comment: @4.Pi.n Any ideas?

Comment: To keep it as simple as possible, you might try a clustering approaches, ex. Using a similarity function to group similar strings with a given probability together, (`ex. 0.8`), then we could define a heuristic search function to extract dates for each group for example (dates commonly consist of numbers, also dates starting index for the same population [data] usually very close to each other). for **JS** you might check [npm-string-similarity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity)

Comment: Try clustering with a heuristic search. Your objective is a little bit simple so using NLP might be not too much worth as it's not always works as expected, even though it's not an easy task to get it work in a few days might take weeks if you are not familiar with NLP and months if you are not familiar with AI algorithms in general.  Alternatively, you might you might try an existing API, but it's preferred to take your time and learn more about Machine Learning, then move to Deep Learning and NLP, it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to use regex for the second of your examples. If you use a capturing group for the "friend name" part you can extract that with ease:

```js
const re = /Jack and ([a-zA-Z]+) are friends/
const inputs = ["Jack and Jones are friends",
"Jack and JC are friends",
"Jack and Irani are friends",
"Bob and John are friends"] // last one wont match

for(let i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
  const match = inputs[i].match(re);
  if(match)
    console.log("friend=",match[1]);
  else
    console.log("No match for the string:", inputs[i])
}
```

The first example is slightly hardeer, but only because the regex is more difficult to write. Assuming the format is always "short month name 2 digit day comma 4 digit year" it is doable

```js
const re = /covid-19 testing status upto ((jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec) (0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]),\d{4})/
const inputs = ["covid-19 testing status upto may 05,2021",
"covid-19 testing status upto may 04,2021",
"covid-19 testing status upto may 01,2021",
"covid-19 testing status upto 01/01/2020"] // wrong date format

for(let i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
  const match = inputs[i].match(re);
  if(match)
    console.log("date=",match[1]);
  else
    console.log("No match for the string:", inputs[i])
}
```

Comment: Does this mean the creation of a new regex for every pattern detected?

Comment: @Amanda pretty much yes. Did you expect to just write `covid-19 testing status upto {{date}}` and the computer magically know what `{{date}}` means?

Comment: Of course not! :) If that helps I was trying to create a system very similar to the flow described here https://youtu.be/B34gHahWX_s It will exactly tell, what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Amanda so which part of that are you trying to do? I suspect that system is using [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) not regex.

Comment: Could we discuss this here at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232070/discussion-between-jamiec-and-amanda

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly unclear to me what your actual inputs and outputs should be.  Here's an attempt that guesses at that.  With inputs like

```
[{
  sample: 'covid-19 testing status upto may 05,2021',
  extract: 'may 05,2021',
  propName: 'date'
}, {
  sample: 'Jack and Jones are friends',
  extract: 'Jones',
  propName: 'friend-name'
}]
```

we generate a function which can be used like this:

```
mySubs ('Jack and William are friends')
//=> {"friend-name": "William"}
```

or

```js
(mySubs ('covid-19 testing status upto apr 30,2021')
//=> {"date": "apr 30,2021"}
```

or

```js
mySubs ('Jack and Jessica are friends who dicsussed covid-19 testing status upto apr 27,2021')
//=> {"date": "apr 27,2021", "friend-name": "Jessica"}
```

and which would yield an empty object if nothing matched.

We do this by dynamically generating regular expressions for our samples, ones which will capture the substitutions made:

```js
const regEscape = (s) =>
  s .replace (/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');


const makeTester = ({sample, extract, propName}) => ({
  regex: new RegExp (
    regEscape (sample .slice (0, sample .indexOf (extract))) + 
    '(.+)' + 
    regEscape (sample .slice (sample .indexOf (extract) + extract .length))
  ), 
  propName
})

const substitutes = (configs, testers = configs .map (makeTester)) => (sentence) =>
  Object.assign( ...testers .flatMap (({regex, propName}) => {
    const match = sentence .match (regex)
    return (match)
      ? {[propName]: match[1]}
      : {}
  }))

const configs = [{
  sample: 'covid-19 testing status upto may 05,2021',
  extract: 'may 05,2021',
  propName: 'date'
}, {
  sample: 'Jack and Jones are friends',
  extract: 'Jones',
  propName: 'friend-name'
}]

const mySubs = substitutes (configs)

console .log (mySubs ('Jack and William are friends'))
console .log (mySubs ('covid-19 testing status upto apr 30,2021'))
console .log (mySubs ('Jack and Jessica are friends who dicsussed covid-19 testing status upto apr 27,2021'))
console .log (mySubs ('Some random string that does not match'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If you needed to also report what templates matched, you could add a name to each template, and then carry the results through the two main functions to give results like this:

```js
{"covid": {"date": "apr 27,2021"}, "friends": {"friend-name": "Jessica"}}
```

It's only slightly more complex:

```js
const regEscape = (s) =>
  s .replace (/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');


const makeTester = ({name, sample, extract, propName}) => ({
  regex: new RegExp (
    regEscape (sample .slice (0, sample .indexOf (extract))) + 
    '(.+)' + 
    regEscape (sample .slice (sample .indexOf (extract) + extract .length))
  ),
  propName,
  name
})

const substitutes = (configs, testers = configs.map(makeTester)) => (sentence) =>
  Object.assign( ...testers .flatMap (({name, regex, propName}) => {
    const match = sentence .match (regex)
    return (match)
      ? {[name]: {[propName]: match[1]}}
      : {}
  }))

const configs = [{
  name: 'covid', 
  sample: 'covid-19 testing status upto may 05,2021',
  extract: 'may 05,2021',
  propName: 'date'
}, {
  name: 'friends',
  sample: 'Jack and Jones are friends',
  extract: 'Jones',
  propName: 'friend-name'
}]

const mySubs = substitutes (configs)

console .log (mySubs ('Jack and William are friends'))
console .log (mySubs ('covid-19 testing status upto apr 30,2021'))
console .log (mySubs ('Jack and Jessica are friends who dicsussed covid-19 testing status upto apr 27,2021'))
console .log (mySubs ('Some random string that does not match'))
```

Either way, this has some limitations.  It's hard to figure out what to do if the templates overlap in odd ways, etc.  It's also possible that you want to match only complete sentences, and my examples of double-matching won't make sense.  If so, you can just prepend a `'^'` and append a `'$'` to the string passed to `new RegExp`.

---

Again, this is a guess at your requirements.  The important thing here is that you might be able to dynamically generate regexes to use.